# Hierarchical Update in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hierarchical-data

I got a hive table as follows:

```
 Table A

 docid    corr_docid    header   

 100                    a
 101         100        b
 102                    c
 105         101        d
 106         102        e
 107         106        f
 108         107        g
 109                    h
```

Is it possible to create another table.

Here corr_docid 107 corrects the document with docid 107.

Table B as follows:

```
 Table A

 docid    corr_docid    header   newdocid 

 100                    a          105
 101         100        b          105
 102                    c          108
 105         101        d          105
 106         102        e          108 
 107         106        f          108
 108         107        g          108
 109                    h          109
```

Is this possible in hive.

Comment: Couldn't clearly understand your requirement, but have you tried lead/lag/last_value functions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this native SQL to get desired result, This will work only if you know the hierarchy depth/level, is 4 here.

```
`select a.docid,
a.corr_docid,
case when b.docid  is null then a.docid 
when c.docid is null then b.docid
when d.docid is null then c.docid 
else d.docid
end newdocid
from Table_A a left join Table_A b on a.docid = b.corr_docid 
left join Table_A c  on b.docid = c.corr_docid  
left join Table_A d on c.docid = d.corr_docid ;`
```

Comment: Rewrite `newdocid` using COALESCE

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this using CTEs as given in this link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/step-by-step-guide-creating-sql-hierarchical-queries-bibhas-mitra